# Can i have generic member variables in c++?

Tags: c++, sql, generics, inheritance

so i am writing an interface in c++ that should communicate with a sql server database. i have a lot of tables that look like this:

| id | name | description | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

the id is a foreign key to another table. lets say i have like 10 tables of this type. All of these tables have the above mentioned fields but might have some additional columns which might have different names and be of different datatype. I need to write a C++ interface that can represent all 10 tables. What i am currently doing is writing a distinct struct for every of these 10 tables. This results in a lot of duplicate code. I want to solve this in a very generic way. I.e. lets say i have a base class that looks like this:

```
struct foreignTable
{
    int m_id;
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
};
```

and have derived classes that look something like this:

```
struct derivedTable : public foreignTable
{
    inline static const std::string TABLENAME = 'mytable1';
    inline static const std::vector<std::string> COLUMN_NAMES = {"col1", "col2"};
};
```

This is just a basic and incomplete idea i have, what i really want is a generic way to declare additional "members" of the class and declare which datatype each of these members have. Maybe something like a std::map would do but i currently can not imagine how this would even look like.

If i would do this in python i would just declare a dict for the additional columns and have generic key value pairs where i do not care about type info.

So i hope someone can point me in the right direction how something like this would be achieved?

**EDIT**: to answer the question why this is causing duplicate code:
i am using [otl](https://otl.sourceforge.net/) as my database backend. I have a database class that looks like this:

db.hpp

```
#ifndef DATABASE_HPP
#define DATABASE_HPP

#define OTL_ODBC_MSSQL_2008
#define OTL_STREAM_READ_ITERATOR_ON
#define OTL_STL
#define OTL_CPP_17_ON
#define OTL_ANSI_CPP
#include <string_view>
#define OTL_STD_STRING_VIEW_CLASS std::string_view
#include "otlv4.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

otl_stream &operator>>(otl_stream &s, derivedTableData1 &data)
{
    s >> data.m_id >> data.m_name >> data.m_description /* >> ... additional column data */;
    return s;
}

class Database:
{
private:
    otl_connect db;

    void logException(otl_exception &p)
    {
        std::cout << p.msg << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.code << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.var_info << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.sqlstate << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.stm_text << std::endl;
    }

public:
    
    Database()
    {
        otl_connect::otl_initialize();
    }

    ~Database()
    {
         db.logoff();
    }
    
    void connect(const std::string &connect_string)
    {
        try
        {
            db.rlogon(connect_string.c_str());
        }
        catch(otl_exception &p)
        {
             logException(p);
        }
    }

    // think of this function duplicated for each table i have
    // ideally i would have one template function here instead 
    // that can deal with my requirements
    std::vector<derivedTableData1> query_getTable1()
    {
        // one entry in this vector is one row in one of the 10 tables i mentioned
        std::vector<derivedTableData1> result;
        int count;   // number of rows in table
        try
        {
            otl_stream q1(1, ("select count(*) from " + derivedTableData1::TABLENAME).c_str(), db);
            q1 >> count;
            otl_stream q2(count, ("select id, name, description /* ... additional columns */ from " + derivedTableData1::TABLENAME).c_str(), db);
            std::copy(
                otl_input_iterator<derivedTableData1, ptrdiff_t>(q2),
                otl_input_iterator<derivedTableData1, ptrdiff_t>(),
                back_inserter(result)
            );
        }
        catch(otl_exception &p)
        {
            logException(p);
        } 
    return result;
    }
    // std::vector<derivedTableData1> query_getTable2()
    // ...

};
#endif
```

`std::vector<derivedTableData1> query_getTable1()` is duplicated 10 times, once for each table. The same goes for the stream operater >> to copy the data to the corresponding struct

**EDIT2:** i mean templating the `query_getTableData1` function would be easy:

```
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> query_getTable()
    {
        // one entry in this vector is one row in one of the 10 tables i mentioned
        std::vector<T> result;
        int count;   // number of rows in table
        try
        {
            otl_stream q1(1, ("select count(*) from " + T::TABLENAME).c_str(), db);
            q1 >> count;
            otl_stream q2(count, ("select id, name, description " + /* ... loop over T::COLUMN_NAMES */ + "from " + derivedTableData1::TABLENAME).c_str(), db);
            std::copy(
                otl_input_iterator<T, ptrdiff_t>(q2),
                otl_input_iterator<T, ptrdiff_t>(),
                back_inserter(result)
            );
        }
        catch(otl_exception &p)
        {
            logException(p);
        } 
    return result;
    }
```

but how would i template the stream operator>> to push the results into the correct members/fields/whatever of the derivedTable1 struct?

Comment: What about using templates with variable number of arguments?

Comment: @Ripi2 so something like a variadic template? Sorry i am not to versed in template code so i can not imagine how i would code the column names into this. But it sounds like a valid approach i might look into.

Comment: there are open source libraries out there for communicating with databases, some of which provide ORM, which is the kinda thing you seem to want -- I'd research those first. Or if you have C++20, use something like boost pfr (https://github.com/boostorg/pfr) where you can automatically get the names + references to the members from an object.

Comment: Also not an answer, but I had good experience with a library called ODB that is a non-opinionated ORM where the "generic" part of defining tables is just writing C++ classes where the columns are the fields.

Comment: map of std::variant ?

Comment: "This results in a lot of duplicate code. " Why is that causing duplicate code?

Comment: @MooingDuck see my edit

Comment: @TooTone Thanks! orm looks interesting and i wasn't aware of this, certainly worth looking into!

Comment: "but how would i template the stream operator>> to push the results into the correct members/fields/whatever of the derivedTable1 struct?"
You don't. You just make separate `operator>>(otl_stream &s, derivedTableData1 &data)` just like the one you already have. You already have the right code right there, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've already figured most of it out. Start with a base class that implements everything in common across your ten tables. Subclass from that for each specific table.

Your base class can be abstract, and you can implement concrete methods for anything specific. Standard polymorphism.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with using a `std::vector<std::variant>`, here is the code i came up with

*basicTable.hpp*

```
#ifndef A_BASICTABLE_HPP
#define A_BASICTABLE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <variant>

typedef std::variant<int, float, double, bool, std::string> column_type;



struct BasicTable
{
    /*
     * should be overriden by derived structs with column names
     * - first element is base column name which we can use as key in std::unordered_map
     * - second element is needed when we want to cast/convert the sql column to a different type in DBInterface::query_getTable()
     * example:
     * std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("zeitstempel", "convert(varchar(max), [zeitstempel], 120)")
     */
    inline static const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> COLUMN_NAMES;

    template<typename T>
    T &get(const std::string &key)
    {
        return *std::get_if<T>(&_data[key]);
    }

    column_type &operator[](const std::string &key)
    {
        return _data[key];
    }

protected:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, column_type> _data;
};


#endif
```

one of the derived classes may look something like this

```
#ifndef A_TABLE1_HPP
#define A_TABLE1_HPP

#include "basicTable.hpp"

// represents one row in table1
struct Table1Row : public BasicTable
{
    inline static const std::string TABLENAME = "table1";

    inline static const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> COLUMN_NAMES =
    {
        std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("id", "id"),
        std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("name", "name"),
        std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("description", "description"),
        std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("created_by", "created_by"),
        std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("timestamp", "convert(varchar(max), [timestamp], 120)")
    };
};

#endif
```

my database class now looks like this

```
#ifndef DATABASE_HPP
#define DATABASE_HPP

#define OTL_ODBC_MSSQL_2008
#define OTL_STREAM_READ_ITERATOR_ON
#define OTL_STL
#define OTL_CPP_17_ON
#define OTL_ANSI_CPP
#include <string_view>
#define OTL_STD_STRING_VIEW_CLASS std::string_view
#include "otlv4.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


// stream into std::variant
// typedef std::variant<int, float, double, bool, std::string> column_type
// defined in basicTable.hpp
otl_stream &operator>>(otl_stream &s, column_type &cur)
{
    // refer to https://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_stream_class.htm#otl_var_dbtype for integer codes for ftype description
    otl_var_desc* desc = s.describe_next_out_var();
    switch (desc->ftype)
    {
        case (1): // null terminated string
        {
            std::string val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (2): // double
        {
            double val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (3): //float
        {
            float val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (4): // int
        {
            int val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (5): // unsigned int
        {
            int val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (6): // short int
        {
            int val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (7): // long int
        {
            int val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (9): // varchar long
        {
            std::string val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        case (20): // big int
        {
            int val; s >> val; cur = val; break;
        }
        default:
        {
            std::cout << "type not implemented: " << desc->ftype << std::endl;
            std::cout << "for column: " << desc->name << std::endl;
        }
    };
    return s;
}

otl_stream &operator>>(otl_stream &s, Table1Row &table1)
{
    for(auto &col : Table1Row::COLUMN_NAMES)
        s >> table1[col.first];

    return s;
}

class Database:
{
private:
    otl_connect db;

    void logException(otl_exception &p)
    {
        std::cout << p.msg << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.code << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.var_info << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.sqlstate << std::endl;
        std::cout << p.stm_text << std::endl;
    }

public:
    
    Database()
    {
        otl_connect::otl_initialize();
    }

    ~Database()
    {
         db.logoff();
    }
    
    void connect(const std::string &connect_string)
    {
        try
        {
            db.rlogon(connect_string.c_str());
        }
        catch(otl_exception &p)
        {
             logException(p);
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    int getCount()
    {
        int count;
        try
        {
            otl_stream q1(1, ("select count(*) from " + T::TABLENAME).c_str(), db);
            q1 >> count;
        }
        catch(otl_exception &p)
        {
            logException(p);
        }

    return count;
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> query_getTable()
    {
        std::vector<T> result;
        int count;

        std::string query_str = "select ";

        // set up query from additional column names
        for(int idx = 0; idx < T::COLUMN_NAMES.size(); idx++)
        {
            query_str = query_str + T::COLUMN_NAMES[idx].second;
            if(idx + 1 < T::COLUMN_NAMES.size()) query_str += ", ";
        }
        query_str = query_str + " from " + T::TABLENAME;

        try
        {
            count = getCount<T>();

            otl_stream q(count, query_str.c_str(), db);

            std::copy(
                    otl_input_iterator<T, ptrdiff_t>(q),
                    otl_input_iterator<T, ptrdiff_t>(),
                    back_inserter(result)
            );
        }
        catch(otl_exception &p)
        {
            std::cout << "Exception in query: " << query_str << std::endl;
            logException(p);
        }

        return result;
    }

};
#endif
```

now i can readily get the table data with the following code:

```
std::vector<Table1Row> t1data = db.query_getTable<Table1Row>();

//retrieve id from first row
int id = t1data[0].get<int>("id");

//retrieve name from first row
std::string name = t1data[0].get<std::string>("name");
```

might not be perfect yet but works so far. Thanks for the suggestions!